# Can I get Siri to not bleep out Bitches Brew when I ask to hear that album?

Tags: ios, siri, apple-music, homepod

I use Apple Music and have HomePod and Siri audibly bleeps out words (and prints B**** on the screen for the example below) on song and album titles rather than pronouncing and displaying them faithfully.

One is “Hey Siri, play the album *Bitches Brew*”

- I see no place in the home app to set explicit music allowed or banned.
- My region is US and my date of birth confirms I’m over 21.
- I see no place at https://appleid.apple.com to opt in to less bleeping.
- If I search the settings app on iPhone or iPad, there is no setting I can find for the search term explicit.
- iOS 13.3.1

Another reproducible album is *Honky Chateau* by Elton John.

I’m fine if these bleep by default, but I’d like Siri to be able to tell met what song is playing without redaction a song I explicitly have added to my library.

Am I missing a lever that I can pull or setting to get Siri to bleep music names less broadly or just skip the redaction entirely?

Comment: Does it censor song titles as well?

Comment: @IconDaemon yes it also censor song titles

Comment: Out of curiosity, what exactly does Siri say? Does it just remote the offending word or the whole title? Is there an actual sitcom-esque sound effect?

Comment: It asterisks the word. Just tried it myself (Monterey).

Me: 'Play Bitches Brew' [typed in full on screen as I say it].
Siri : 'Now playing B*****s Brew' [complete with your sitcom bleep].